# Elasticsearch keyword not generated

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I have elastic search entry with text field value as

```
14-Apr-2023 20:44:46.693 INFO [pool-2-thread-24] com.xyz.log [app_id:uuid] calling execute-task with url=https://example.com/api/applications/uuid/tasks/TASK_NAME/execute/, body=workflow_id=uuid variables={
```

I'm trying to generate scripted field from this. my script looks like below

```
if(doc.containsKey('@message') ) {
    if (doc.containsKey('@message.keyword')) {
        if(doc['@message.keyword'].size()==0){
            return "doc[@message.keyword].size()==0"
        }
        else {     
            String message= doc['@message.keyword'].value;
            int start=message.indexOf('[');
            int end=message.indexOf(']');
            String x= message.substring(start+1,end);
            return x;
        }
    }
    else { return "!doc.containsKey('@message.keyword')"; }
} else { return "!doc.containsKey('@message')"; }
```

I'm getting evaluated value as `doc[@message.keyword].size()==0`. for some other values I'm able to extract correct value i.e. `pool-2-thread-24`

Can someone help me identifying issue please.
Why is `doc.containsKey('@message.keyword')` but `doc['@message.keyword'].size()` zero?

Mapping (auto gnerated):

```
{
  "dpprod-workflow-web.2023.04" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "@log_group" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "@log_stream" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "@message" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "@owner" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

same script is working for value:

```
19-Apr-2023 15:10:28.113 FINE [Thread-4] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logDebug ENGINE-13011 closing existing command context
```

and generating expected result `Thread-4`

Is there any reason keyword is not generated for text being too long or having special characters?

Also tried with using `@message` instead of `@message.keyword` after setting field_data=true, there I'm getting value as `0a9b7ed24c9b12` instead of actual string

Comment: Can you please add the mapping you're using and the full query? At first I thought this would be a runtime field but it can't be because you're mixing keyword and bool return types (which is generally something I would avoid since it will break assumptions around mappings).

Comment: @xeraa I've updated question with mapping details, looks like for some values keyword is generated but for some, it is not generated

Comment: Update: after using fielddata=true I am mostly getting some hex codes in @message field, but when I dug deeper, issue is only with entries ending with `{` for entries without `{` it is working well.

Comment: You should use the .keyword field instead. fielddata is prone to explode your heap and is really discouraged. for the curly braces, it sounds like you'd need a grok pattern to handle those and just store the desired string?